# Issues building kernel on FreeBSD 12 RC1: Cannot find stdlib.h

Tags: kernel, freebsd

While building a specific netgraph module on a FreeBSD 12 RC1 machine, I get the following error with a custom netgraph module

```
/usr/src/sys/netgraph/ng_custom.c:126:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
#include <stdlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The same code builds just fine on FreeBSD 11.1-Release. The build is being done using the nanobsd build system.

I get a similar issue when building a file that references:

The build command in the log is:

```
cc -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.0 
--sysroot=/usr/obj/nanobsd.testos/usr/src/amd64.amd64/tmp 
-B/usr/obj/nanobsd.testos/usr/src/amd64.amd64/tmp/usr/bin -O2 -pipe 
-fno-strict-aliasing -Werror -D_KERNEL -DKLD_MODULE -DKLD_TIED -nostdinc 
-DHAVE_KERNEL_OPTION_HEADERS -include     
/usr/obj/nanobsd.testos/usr/src/amd64.amd64/sys/testos/opt_global.h -I. 
-I/usr/src/sys -I/usr/src/sys/contrib/ck/include -fno-common -g 
-fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer 
-I/usr/obj/nanobsd.testos/usr/src/amd64.amd64/sys/testos -Dtestos -MD 
-MF.depend.ng_custom.o -MTng_custom.o -mcmodel=kernel -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx    
-mno-sse -msoft-float -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -ffreestanding -fwrapv 
-fstack-protector -gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs 
-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wundef 
-Wno-pointer-sign -D__printf__=__freebsd_kprintf__ -Wmissing-include-dirs 
-fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-unknown-pragmas 
-Wno-error-tautological-compare -Wno-error-empty-body 
-Wno-error-parentheses-equality -Wno-error-unused-function 
-Wno-error-pointer-sign -Wno-error-shift-negative-value 
-Wno-address-of-packed-member -mno-aes -mno-avx -std=iso9899:1999 
-c /usr/src/sys/netgraph/ng_custom.c -o ng_custom.o
```

I see the "-nostdinc" and assume that this is what's causing the issue. How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: How do you build it, exactly?

Comment: cd /usr/src/tools/tools/nanobsd
sh nanobsd.sh -c nanobsd.conf

Comment: You should be using `bsd.kmod.mk` -- look how kernel-modules in the `/usr/src/sys` tree are built.